# Why can't I comment on my deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Why can't I comment on my deleted post if I don't agree with the reasons for deletion?

My answer to [What Stack Overflow is Not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128596#128596) was deleted, but I don't believe syntax checking and grammar/spell checking are the same.

Comment: +1 to [lunbocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163265/lunboks) &[Daniel Fischer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177145/daniel-fischer). I should have known. Thanks.

Comment: You _can_ comment on their posts, you know that?

Comment: It's wiki post - you can add whatever you have in mind to the existing answer instead of writing it as separate answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only moderators can comment on deleted posts.

If you want to get your answer undeleted, you can flag it for moderation attention, or open a question on the meta site; between the two, the first is preferable.

In this case, I would say that your answer is already included in [the answer already given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128558#128558).

> We expect you to put a minimal amount of effort into your post to make it look professional. We expect:
>
> - Proper spelling, capitalization, grammar and punctuation.
> - Your post to be clear and understandable
> - A good title that can be effectively searched by Google
> - Your code to compile
>
> Capitalization is especially problematic. If your shift key is broken, get it fixed. If you're posting from a cell phone or other mobile device, there are settings on the phone that will automatically capitalize and fix misspellings for you.
>
> You want the community to focus on your problem, not your post's problems. It's not fair to the community to ask them to answer your question, and clean up your post also.

Your deleted answer contained the following text.

> Whilst we are here to help with general programming problems, questions which could have been answered by carefully checking the syntax of your code or using a syntax highlighting editor/IDE will probably be downvoted or closed as NARQ.
>
> This kind of question clearly demonstrates lack of research effort and is definitely not useful to anybody else.

Answer (score 9):

Because you can't comment on deleted posts, that's just how it works.

You can, however, edit your post to try and address potential problems, and/or flag it for moderator review if you disagree with its deletion.

If that fails, argue your case on meta, which it looks like is what you're doing right now, but of course I can't comment because I have no idea what your answer was.

Answer (score 7):

You can flag for moderator attention if you disagree with the deletion. That's far more effective than a mere comment would be. But you need a good argument to convince the moderator(s) that your post merits undeletion. Editing and improving your post can, and usually need to, be part of a strong argument for undeletion.